# Assistance needed with a global procmailrc file

Tags: linux, postfix, procmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assistance needed with a global procmailrc file](https://serverfault.com/questions/322705/assistance-needed-with-a-global-procmailrc-file)
>   [Creating a global procmailrc file that forwards to an Exchange server](https://serverfault.com/questions/322868/creating-a-global-procmailrc-file-that-forwards-to-an-exchange-server)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Please close, as this now a duplicate

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I'm new to procmail, so please be forgiving.

I have a postfix server on my network that (eventually) will receive a bounced message from our Sonicwall Spam Filter when a message attachment exceeds a certain size.  The postfix server is configured to create mailboxes based on LDAP (using usernames from our Active Directory).

I need to create a global procmailrc file that saves the attachments to a folder, removes the attachments, then forwards the original message sans attachments to our Exchange server along with some additional text.  I have the postfix server configured to handle our e-mail addresses (username@domain.com), as this is a requirement of the Sonicwall when it bounces.

I've been working on this for a few hours, and I haven't even gotten to the point where a message sent to my postfix server gets forwarded to the Exchange server.

Please let me know if I'm being clear on what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm more than happy to elaborate.

Also, let me know if I should move this to ServerFault.

Comment: Your filtering problem should be a good fit here, but if you're having trouble getting mail forwarding to work first, that's better suited for ServerFault.

Comment: Yes, should move to ServerFault. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

http://userpages.umbc.edu/~ian/procmail.html

http://www.erehwon.org/erehwon/procmailex.html

http://www.stimpy.net/procmail/tutorial/ref/

http://www.panix.com/~elflord/unix/procmail.html

http://lipas.uwasa.fi/~ts/info/proctips.html

http://support.verio.com/documents/view_article.cfm?doc_id=1212

Comment: seen most of these, but they're fairly generic and aim mostly towards user-based.  I'm looking for a global solution.

Comment: your question is a bit too generic - it would be good if you go more into detail what you tried, and where it's broken.